Django Rest Framework Nested Serialziers
iam using DRF so i make a small blog that have follow/unfollow system that's my models :
class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    objects = CustomUserManager()
    following = models.ManyToManyField(
        'self', through='Follow', symmetrical=False, related_name='followers'
    )
    def follow(self, target_user):
        if self == target_user:
            raise ValueError("You cannot follow yourself.")

        if not self.is_following(target_user):
            Follow.objects.create(follower=self, following=target_user)
            return True
        return False

    def unfollow(self, target_user):
        if self.is_following(target_user):
            Follow.objects.filter(follower=self, following=target_user).delete()
            return True
        return False

    def is_following(self, target_user):
        return Follow.objects.filter(follower=self, following=target_user).exists()

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pictures/', blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    followers_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    following_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    # is_private = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username



class Follow(models.Model):
    follower = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_following')
    following = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_followers')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['follower','following'],  name="unique_followers"),
            models.CheckConstraint(check=~models.Q(follower=models.F("following")), name="no_self_follow")
        ]
        ordering = ["-created_at"]
        
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.follower} follows {self.following}"

and this my view :
class FollowersFollowingViewSet(ViewSet):
    
    @action(detail=True, methods=['GET'])
    def followers(self, request, pk=None):
        target_user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
        followers = Follow.objects.filter(following=target_user).select_related('follower__profile','follower')
        serializer = FollowersSerializer(followers, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    
    @action(detail=True, methods=['GET'])
    def following(self, request, pk=None):
        target_user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
        following = target_user.following.all()
        serializer = FollowingSerializer(following, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

and those my serializers:
class FollowersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    follower = SimpleUserProfileSerializer()  

    class Meta:
        model = Follow
        fields = ['follower']

class FollowingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    following = SimpleUserProfileSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Follow
        fields = ['following']

class SimpleUserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_id = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user.id')  # جلب user.id من العلاقة
    username = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user.username')  # جلب user.username
    first_name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user.first_name')  # جلب user.first_name
    last_name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user.last_name')  # جلب user.last_name

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile  # الموديل الأساسي هو UserProfile
        fields = ['user_id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'profile_picture', 'bio']

and this my output :
[
    {
        "follower": {
            "profile_picture": null,
            "bio": null
        }
    }
]

i just do not understand why he is still returning the just fields that's in profile model
i think it's because of it's a model Serializer and the model set to UserProfile ?
is there any solution or i should make a new serializer in this case ?
i just want him to get all info about all followers

following and follower appear to be User objects, not UserProfile objects, so the serializer should go the other way around.

following and follower appear to be User objects, not UserProfile objects, so the serializer should go the other way around:
class SimpleUserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_id = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='id')  # جلب user.id من العلاقة
    username = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='username')  # جلب user.username
    first_name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(
        source='first_name'
    )  # جلب user.first_name
    last_name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(
        source='last_name'
    )  # جلب user.last_name
    bio = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='profile.bio')
    profile_picture = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='profile.profile_picture')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'user_id',
            'username',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'profile_picture',
            'bio',
        ]


Note: Please don't store aggregates in the model: determine aggregates when needed: storing aggregates in the model makes updating and keeping data in sync harder. You can use .annotate(…) [Django-doc] to generate counts, sums, etc. per object when needed.


I just thinking about retreiving profile it will be a costed query when i can make signals to updated counters

@Mokhtaromar: typically not, especially COUNT, since that uses the B-tree index. Moreover, signals are typically not a good idea either. Disclosure: I am the author of that page.
